# Based signals component is not working properly

Tags: angular, signals

I was trying to play with signals based components. I was reading this question and the answer here: [Angular Signal Based Components. How do I use signals: true property in component decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984211/angular-signal-based-components-how-do-i-use-signals-true-property-in-componen)

but seems that is not working yet for me. I mean, when I try to use signals in @Component() it throws an error. Is this something that is not implemented yet or maybe My CLI is not updated well? I have angular latest version installed.

Here is my Component decorator. But under signals I see a red line throwing the error.

```
@Component({
  signals: true,
  selector: 'app-input-output',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './input-output.component.html',
  styleUrl: './input-output.component.css',
})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you import singal function correctly form @angular/core

please provide full component code snippet for more context.