# 'signals' does not exist in type 'Component'

Tags: angular, signals, angular-components

I'm trying to use Angular Signal Based Components feature. Just seen this on [Angular Signal Based Components. How do I use signals: true property in component decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984211/angular-signal-based-components-how-do-i-use-signals-true-property-in-componen) with v17 release and see the many articles ([https://www.techiediaries.com/signal-based-components-in-angular-17/#:~:text=Signal%2Dbased%20components%20are%20a%20powerful%20new%20feature%20in%20Angular,benefits%20in%20your%20own%20applications](https://www.techiediaries.com/signal-based-components-in-angular-17/#:%7E:text=Signal%2Dbased%20components%20are%20a%20powerful%20new%20feature%20in%20Angular,benefits%20in%20your%20own%20applications) as example) but never seen on official documentation.

However I've updated @angular/core and @angular/cli to the latest versions (respectively 17.2.4 and 17.2.3) but I'm struggling with this compiling error:

'signals' does not exist in type 'Component'

here's my implementation:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
...

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  signals: true,
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css'],
  imports: [
    ...
  ]
})
export default class MyComponent { ... }
```

[image]

So, there's my mistake somewhere or it's just early to use Signal Based Components?

Comment: The first link is not a release but a RFC (Ready For Comments). Such an option isn't released yet (the second link is misleading).

Comment: Signal components are not yet released. Instead you can use the signal, input and model functions for your properties if you want to work with signals.